# Получение информации через request.post и сравнение со значениями в dict

Tags: python-3.x, запрос, хранение-данных

Необходимо, чтобы клиент ввел код, который у него есть, на странице сайта, а python проверил совпадает ли код с тем, что записан в словаре, и, если совпадает, то выдал сообщение в виде `alert("Вы выиграли!)`.

Как должны выглядеть шаблон html и сама функция в python?

Пробовала через `request.post`, но постоянно выдает ошибку `MultiValueDictKeyError`.

Заранее спасибо.

HTML код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/tot/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Введите код<br><br>
    Ваш код: <input type="number" name="cod"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Проверить">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Python код:

```py
def tot(request):
    cod = 123
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = { 'where': request.path }
        resp = render(request, 'tot/code.html', context)

        return resp
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        user_cod = request.POST['cod']
        if user_cod == cod:
            return render(request, 'tot/tot.html')
```

Comment: Екатерина, чтобы сообщество могло Вам помочь, дополните Ваш вопрос кодом.

Comment: А пока, из вариантов: продебажить кусок кода и посмотреть, что находится в ответе на `request.post`, возможно в ответе вовсе нет данных с таким ключом.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/tot/" method="post">  {% csrf_token %}
    Введите код<br><br>
    Ваш код: <input type="number" name="cod"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Проверить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: def tot(request):
    cod = 123
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {
            'where': request.path
        }
        resp = render(request, 'tot/code.html', context)
        return resp
    elif request.method == 'POST':
         user_cod = request.POST['cod']
         if user_cod == cod:
             return render(request, 'tot/tot.html')

Comment: Так, уже что-то. Насколько понимаю, вы используете Django. Проверьте, что находится в `request.POST` при отправке формы. P.S. для этого можно добавить в функцию `print(request.POST)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if user_input_text in the_dict.values():
    # вы угадали
else:
    # вам не повезло
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли!